# Store any transaction in log table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have lots of tables in my SQL Server database. When any action happens, like an `Insert`, `Update`, `Delete`, I want to store the data in a `Log` table as shown here:

`Product` table:

```
| ID  | Name    | Other |
| --- | ------- | ---   |
| 1   | Book    | ...   |
| 2   | Bicycle | ...   |
```

If any Insert, Update or Delete happens, I want to have something like this:

`Log` table:

```
| ID  | RowId   | TableName  | Action |
| --- | ------- | ---------- | ------ |
| 1   | 1       | Product    | Insert |
| 2   | 2       | Product    | Insert |
| 3   | 15      | Category   | Update |
| 4   | 60      | Customer   | Insert |
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) Express edition with Advanced Services - some features might not be available for me (reference to documentation).

For a single table a [trigger](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/SQL-Server-Insert-data-to-another-Table-using-Insert-Update-and-Delete-Triggers.aspx) is a good idea and it works fine, but what about all tables? As the example shows, `Category` and `Customer` tables are other tables in my database.

Comment: Aside... for something that's meant to log **when** an action happened it seems to be missing a column that records the point in time.

Comment: Further aside... SQL Server 2008 (and R2) has been completely unsupported by Microsoft for a number of years now. Consider upgrading to something more modern.

Comment: The fact you are using Express means you have literally no excuse to have not updated when mainstream support ran out (which ran out way back in 2013/2014), yet alone extended; Express is free.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Do you mean the time column? it existed but I just cleared for more clarify. (but in fact the Important thing is how I can track actions of all tables?

Comment: @Larnu   I can't update the database; we have installed this version on client computer if we want to update database, we need to update thousands of customers

Comment: @AlwaysLearning As I said, it's installed on thousands of client's machines we have limitation to update.

Comment: Then it's time to get those 1,000's of clients up to date. Getting them to use completely unsupported software is just negligence; this should have been a project you started on literally *years* ago (I mean, like 7/8 years ago).

Comment: @Larnu I completely agree with you <3, but we are not the owner of this application we just want to get data from this database, in fact this business is third-party application and you are right we never let the user using the outdate application but we have no chooses in this situation.

Comment: If you were using any mainstream version of SQL Server you could utilise *system versioning* that pretty much provides this functionality for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is the number of triggers, you should create; then create a job to create the trigger when a new table has been created. The below code checks the tables that have not that kind of triggers using specific formula of naming. In my example tablename plus '_dml_audit'. You can change it anyway.

```
Set NOCOUNT ON

select Concat (QUOTENAME(sch.name) , '.' , QUOTENAME(tbl.name)) TableNames
into #Tables
    From sys.tables tbl
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch on sch.schema_id = tbl.schema_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.triggers trg on tbl.object_id = trg.parent_id and trg.name like tbl.name + '_dml_audit'
    Where trg.object_id is null

GO

exec sp_MSforeachtable 'IF ''?'' IN (Select TableNames FROM #Tables) Begin PRINT ''?'' END'

Drop Table #Tables
```

For older version that does not support #table use this:

```
Create Table TempTable (TableNames sysname)
GO
Insert TempTable
SELECT Concat ('[', sch.name , '].[' , tbl.name, ']') TableNames
    From sys.tables tbl
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch on sch.schema_id = tbl.schema_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.triggers trg on tbl.object_id = trg.parent_id and trg.name like tbl.name + '_dml_audit'
    Where trg.object_id is null

GO

exec sp_MSforeachtable 'IF ''?'' IN (Select TableNames FROM TempTable) Begin PRINT ''?'' END'
GO
Drop Table TempTable
```

Replace Trigger Definition with the PRINT statement and Define a job for it.

Comment: Just to confirm, The tablename plus '_dml_audit' Is my trigger name, right? And It's work for old tables I mean my exists tables does not have any trigger

Comment: And This syntax is working on SQL Server 2012+ , I'm using SQL server 2008 is possible to write this in different way? `Invalid object name '#Tables'.` `'Concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: @Milad Yes. You should name the triggers like that.  The select statement returns  name of tables that have not the trigger. So the first time you execute the code above , it returns all table and for the second time no table. After creation of another table the query returns the new created table.

Comment: @Milad The answer just updated

Comment: I really appreciate, All the error is gone except one error `'Concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: I realized Concat, just concatenating :))) I replace it with + `'['+ sch.name + '].[' + tbl.name+ ']'` And now is work. special thanks to you Meysam.